# R Fails to Library Packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, homebrew

I am having trouble on getting R to library packages to use tools such as ggplot. I have reinstalled R to try and remedy the issue to no avail. Currently I can install packages normally `install.packages(ggplot2)`  I am later given the potentially key message

> Installing package into ‘/Users/jet/Library/R/arm64/4.1/library’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Installation returns to normal and I select my CRAN mirror and am left with

> The downloaded binary packages are in
> /var/folders/1w/nbtkj1314rnbdv3djd0vm7zw0000gn/T//RtmpOkNNTZ/downloaded_packages

Later when I try and library the packages`library(ggplot)` I receive the following error.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Users/jet/Library/R/arm64/4.1/library/colorspace/libs/colorspace.so':
> dlopen(/Users/jet/Library/R/arm64/4.1/library/colorspace/libs/colorspace.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/r/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
> Referenced from: /Users/jet/Library/R/arm64/4.1/library/colorspace/libs/colorspace.so
> Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/r/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file)

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: So you're using a `homebrew` version of R? Is there any reason you really need to do that rather than using the official R release from https://www.r-project.org/? Most of these problems go away when you use the official R release.

Comment: @MrFlick, I see a lot of questions on SO about homebrew-based problems, and you are often one to leave a similar comment. It might be useful to find the best question (or ask a more general question and self-answer with [tag:r-faq]) and combine several of the discussions into one community answer. I'm not a homebrew user so can't speak to it personally other than ... I see lots of questions about it.

Comment: @r2evans I don't use homebrew either so I'm not sure if there's a better way. I always get the best results avoiding it. It's possible they have some other way that you're supposed to install packages not using the normal `install.packages`. Like they might have a way to install R packages via `brew` itself. I guess I don't really have enough good info to make an FAQ about these problems but I agree that the problem does appear more than it probably should.

Comment: I added `homebrew` as a tag; maybe someone who reads that tag can provide some authoritative advice.

Comment: Not `homebrew` user here either, but is this a problem with one or more of the default library paths (`.libPaths()`) used to install packages and lack of access to that?  You can specify the `lib=` in `install.packages()`.  Then you just make sure that your new library path is added to `.libPaths()` and it might work.